# How do I prove that $[\frac{x}{n}]+[\frac{x+1}{n}]+[\frac{x+2}{n}]....+[\frac{x+n-1}{n}]=[x]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How do I prove that $[\frac{x}{n}]+[\frac{x+1}{n}]+[\frac{x+2}{n}]....+[\frac{x+n-1}{n}]=[x]$

How to start?

thanks

Comment: Give a definition of the function prescribed by $x\mapsto[x]$. Is it ceil,floor or something else?

Comment: greatest integer function. Isn't this standard notation btw?

Comment: @J.Deff Some people use it for nearest integer, so there's a bit of confusion.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%27s_identity, also see related questions.

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Use the fact that $[t]$ is the only integer such that $t - 1 \lt [t] \le t $

$\frac{x}{n} -1 +\frac{x+1}{n} - 1+\frac{x+2}{n} - 1…+\frac{x+n-1}{n} -1 \lt [\frac{x}{n}]+[\frac{x+1}{n}]+[\frac{x+2}{n}]…+[\frac{x+n-1}{n}] \le \frac{x}{n} + \frac{x+1}{n}+\frac{x+2}{n}…+\frac{x+n-1}{n}$

**UPDATE**

The OP question can be proved using Hermite's identity, by taking $x := \frac x n$ 
My hint was not useful at all, so please remove the acceptance.

Comment: How do you continue from this? This inequality shows that $(\sum [\frac{x+i}{n}])-x$ is $O(n)$, but I don't see how to use it to obtain $(\sum [\frac{x+i}{n}])-x$ is $O(1)$. (I proved the inequality by dividing $x$ by $n$ with remainder)

Comment: I would really like to hear your explanation on the last line and how it can help us with the given problem. The obtained bound isn't tight enough to conclude the claim. For example let $x=6,n=4$. Then we have that:

$$3.5 < [\frac{6}{4}]+[\frac{7}{4}]+[\frac{8}{4}]+[\frac{9}{4}] < 7.5$$

How can we conclude that $[\frac{6}{4}]+[\frac{7}{4}]+[\frac{8}{4}]+[\frac{9}{4}]  = 6$?